# Trigonometric series convergent to $0$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-series

I was wondering whether there exist $(c_k)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ in $\mathbb{C},$ not all $0,$ so that $\lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{|k| \le K} c_ke^{2\pi i kx} = 0$ for a.e. $x \in [0,1]$. Of course the answer is "no" provided that $\sum_k |c_k|^2 < \infty$. This is all I got.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, such series exist. They can be obtained by letting $c_k = \int_0^1 e^{-2\pi i k x}d\mu(x)$ for certain singular measures $\mu$ (sometimes called Menshov measures). Most Cantor-type measures work for this purpose, although the standard middle-third Cantor measure does not.

A set $E\subset [0,1]$ is a *set of uniqueness* if the only trigonometric series that converges to $0$ on $[0,1]\setminus E$ is the series of zero coefficients. Your question amounts to asking whether there exists a set of measure zero that is **not** a set of uniqueness. The affirmative answer was given by Menshov in 1916. The [Wikipedia article on sets of uniqueness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_of_uniqueness) outlines the history of the subject, gives references, and adds the following curious fact:

> Salem and Zygmund showed that a Cantor-like set with dissection ratio $\xi$ is a set of uniqueness if and only if $1/\xi$ is a Pisot number, that is an algebraic integer with the property that all its conjugates (if any) are smaller than $1$.